# ExceptionNotifier and rake:db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations, exception-notification

App and migrations work fine locally but `rake db:migrate` fails on the server with this error:

```
undefined method `new' for ExceptionNotifier:Module
```

The only migration I'm trying to run passed locally and looks like this:

```
def change
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.remove :admin
  end
  change_column :users, :state, :string, :default => "client"
end
```

No clue what's causing it. And yeah, I am using the [exception notification](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification) gem. Any thoughts? Thanks!